# Mayavi Python - is Enthought distribution mandatory?

Tags: python, dll, module, enthought, mayavi

I would like to use mayavi for 3d data visualization. I downloaded Mayavi module package, as well as dependencies VTK, wxpython, conjigobj. At compile time with IDLE, I have nevertheless a warning

No module named traits.api. I find that this module is distributed with Entought, so that I am wondering whether I can ever use mayavi without using Enthought distribution. Is there some free Enthought disribution available?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you can use the library without the enthought distribution. Linux users usually install these modules using their package manager. For windows, there is [python(x,y)](http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/) which includes the enthought toolkits. The import scope however is misleading sometimes. In some examples it's `traits.api`, others read `enthought.traits.api`. You might want to check which one is true for your python installation.

Comment: Thanks. Althought I am using python(x,y), import traits.api or enthought.traits.api are not working. how to remedy?

Comment: This is very confusing, in some examples they import "enthought.traits.ui.api" or "traits.ui.api". Does this import work for you?